# Can not access cookies in spring jersey based application

Tags: java, spring, rest, cookies, jersey-client

I am working on spring security implementation module and i need to set and get few cookies. i have tried creating cookies by using (`javax.servlet.http.Cookie`) and (`javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie`) both are working fine for setting cookies, i can see the cookies in the browser but when i am trying to access them, it does give me only JSESSIONID, i need to access other cookies also.

This is how i am setting the cookies, and in both ways i will save the cookies successfully on the browser:

```
Cookie cookieOne = new Cookie("SERVLETCOOKIE", "TESTING COOKIES");

NewCookie cookieTwo = new NewCookie("WSRSCOOKIE", "TESTING COOKIES");
```

when i try to access the cookies, i have tried both @Autowired and @Context as below, but i can only get JSESSIONID cookie.

```
@Autowired HttpServletRequest request;
and 
@Context HttpServletRequest request;
```

and i am trying to access the cookies as below :

```
Cookie[] cookieList = request.getCookies();

        if(cookieList !=null && cookieList.length >0){
            for(int i=0;i<cookieList.length;i++){
                Cookie cookie = cookieList[i];

                if(cookie.getName().equals("SERVLETCOOKIE")){
                    String value1 = cookie.getValue();
                    logger.info("cookie found. value ="+value1 );
                }
                if(cookie.getName().equals("WSRSCOOKIE")){
                        String value2 = cookie.getValue();
                        logger.info("cookie found. value ="+value2 );
                    }
                }
            }
```

It would be great if someone help me point out the way i can get all the other cookies.

Comment: So all you do is just create Cookie object instance? You don't add them to the actual response?

Comment: I have added the cookie objects to the response, and that's how i can see them on the browser. Let me know if you know how i can access them back, for now i can only access JSESSIONID as i mentioned in my question. Thanks

Comment: thanks guys for your views and those who really spent time to answer it, i end up resolving the issue by using (javax.servlet.http.Cookie) and setting up domain and path to it. This is my observation, in the security configurations file where we set http patterns for /oauth/token and url to secure our APIs i changed the create-session from "never" to "always" that let me have a JSESSIONID cookie, i went through each and every properties of it and found out i was not setting path and domain in my cookies, after i set these two properties i can access my cookies now.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a few years old. However today I had a similar problem.
The solution was: If you are using the Apache http connector then the jersey cookie api seems not to be supported.
Try to get the cookies over the Apache api:

```
public static Cookie getCookie(final ClientRequestContext clientRequestContext, final String key){
    final CookieStore cookieStore = ApacheConnectorProvider.getCookieStore(clientRequestContext.getClient());
    return cookieStore.getCookies().stream().filter(c->c.getName().equals(key)).collect(CollectorUtil.singletonOrNullCollector());
}
```